# Waterproofing stucco over OSB

Tags: waterproofing, stucco, osb

I have a legacy window that I am boarding up, for reasons of interior layout.

As the surrounding wall is stucco finish, I want to do the same over the boarded up window. I was thinking to just screw some lathe over the OSB and then stucco over.

However, I am concerned about waterproofing.

Should I apply some material over the OSB to waterproof it, like maybe roofing felt paper or vapor barrier (*the latter may impede adhesion of stucco*)?

[image]

Comment: Stucco isn't supposed to adhere to the OSB, that's what the lath is for.

Comment: doing it right would be bricks like the rest of the wall.  what's above that rotten wood at the top? a brick arch? a concrete lintel?

Comment: @Jasen I will put a layer of 1x lumber over it